# What is UpdateClusterInternal operation? Kubernetes on GKE / GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The following operation was carried out (in what appears to be a scheduled task) on our default node pool.

```
google.container.internal.ClusterManagerInternal.UpdateClusterInternal was executed on default-pool
```

What does this mean?

It caused a few problems, that I believe are due to some stateful code creeping into one of our pods. We can fix the code but quite keen to know what task was.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation ‘Periodically, the GKE team performs automatic upgrades of your cluster master on your behalf.’[here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/versioning-and-upgrades#automatic_master_upgrades)

The 'UpdateClusterInternal' means that, there was a upgrade in version which was triggered internally by the GKE team.